# restoring the database dump but not want to change the fields of the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, mysql

I want to restore the database dump on the current application on local.

Thing is that I want to store the data of the first version of the site to the second version of the site but problem is  in the second version there are new tables and fields are added and which are not in first version.

so when I restore the first version dump on the second version then newly created fields are deleted .

I am using mysql query browse .

can you please suggest me what to do on local as well on live.

**EDIT**

For example

In second version I have 10 fields and in first version I have 8 fields in user table.

Now I want to user the record of the first version in second version so I run sql dump of first version on second version database but first version have only 8 fields so 2 new ceated fields are deleted.

I want the same number of fields wit the record of version one.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you dump second version ? =) First version of your app will be also be supported.

Comment: manually edit the dump to comment `drop` statements and to include constraints for new columns if necessary.

Comment: @itsnikolay when I restore dump first version on second version database then newly created fields are deleted in second version.

Comment: Can you use migration utility from `MySQL workbench`?

Comment: (for future) don't delete old data if you gonna support both versions.  Also it's a solution for your problem. Try to create migration when you have both tables (or fields).

Comment: @itsnikolay I think you have not understood the question please read after EDIT.